# How to bind id value to form.value and submit data in reactive?

Tags: html, angular

I am using a reactive form.
I have displayed the company list as a dropdown. I want to take its id only and store it in DB with other form values.

Angular reactive

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" for="exampleInputPassword1">  
 <div class="d-block my-3">    
 <div class="mb-3">
 <select class="custom-select"  formControlName = "companyName">
 <option value="">Choose Company</option>
<option  *ngFor="let obj of companyList; let i = index" [value]="companyList[i].companyName">{{obj.companyName}}</option>
 </select>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
insertUser(){
this.uObj=this.form.value;
this.service.inssertUser("siteBookCreate",this.uObj).subscribe(data=>this.u  Obj=data);
}
```

````
```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-publish"
[disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="inserUser(form.value)">Save <i style="font-size:22px;margin-left:10px;"></i> </button>
````

```
not able to get id of company
```

Comment: can you share a stackblitz for above code?(ps: do you want id of company from **Select**) because i think by mistake you returned [value]="companyList[i].companyName"  company name not id.  also use **obj.id** for better run time computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the [value] attribute of your option tag

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" for="exampleInputPassword1">  
     <div class="d-block my-3">    
      <div class="mb-3">
       <select class="custom-select"  formControlName = "companyName">
        <option value="">Choose Company</option>
          <option  *ngFor="let obj of companyList; let i = index" 
          [value]="companyList[i].companyID">    
          {{obj.companyName}}</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you properly configured your form, it should be enough if you add `this.uObj=this.form.value.companyName` . If something else is missing it would be great if you could add stackblitz or something like this.